# Generate data and curve fit from an equation with Y on both sides

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I want to fit the curves generated by this equation (1) :

```
(1) ID=K*(W/L)*[(VG-VT*(ID*RD/2))**(alpha-1) * (VD-ID*RD)-(1-1/alpha)*(VD-ID*RD)**alpha]
```

However the variable 'ID' is on both sides. I am tyring to find a way to modify the code given in this example from scipy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

#the function for ID, with ID in the arguments. 
def func(K, W, L, VG, VT, ID, RD, alpha, VD ):
    return K*(W/L)*[(VG-VT*(ID*RD/2))**(alpha-1) * (VD-ID*RD)-(1-1/alpha)*(VD-ID*RD)**alpha]

#x_data
VG_data = np.linspace(-6, 16, 300)

#y_data: ID is also an argument of the function here
ID = func(VG=VG_data, K=5.2*1e-7, W=320*1e-6, L=20*1e-6, VT=0.68, VD=5e-3, alpha=2.2, RD=5.79)



popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, VG_data, ID)
popt

plt.plot(VG_data, func(VG_data, *popt), 'r-')
```

When I run it, I obviously get the error when trying to generate ID:

```py
---> 27 ID = func(VG=VG_data, K=5.2*1e-7, W=320*1e-6, L=20*1e-6, VT=0.68, VD=5e-3, alpha=2.2, RD=5.79)
     28 
     29 

TypeError: func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ID'
```

How do I generate and fit data when I have the 'y' variable on both sides?

**EDIT**

I'm adding a link to example data (VG, ID) and the code to plot it:

import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```py
url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leoUninova/Transistor-altair-plots/master/df1.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(url)
#a single transistor data
df=df.loc[df.Name=='300-250-10.0-10.0']
VG=df.VG
ID=df.absID
plt.plot(VG,ID)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The definition of func() in your code requires nine arguments, yet you only pass eight. This gives the "missing argument" error.

Comment: yes, I know, my question is more how do I avoid it? since my equation has the ID term on both sides, how do I write the function so that I can pass the values ?

Comment: When you generate the data, you can pass in a named variable like "ID=ID" just as you are doing to pass in the other named variables such as "VG=VG_data".

Comment: That would work for the 'curve fitting part', but what about when I am generating the data? as I would like to be able to simulate curves from this data. if I pass ID=ID I get 'name ID not defiined'.

Comment: So do you also have data for ID that you are trying to fit to? And perhaps this problem is better written as an ODE, if you can give an expression for e.g. `d(ID)/dt`, and know it's initial value?

Comment: @tBuLi I do have ID, I've edited my question with an example of the data and a plot. However I would also like to generate ID data having everything else.